# Adding condition if in attr of form_widget

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to display **checked** if a variable is null so I have make this code

```
{{ form_widget(form.showPrice, {% if travel is null %}  {'attr': {'checked': 'checked'}} {% endif %} ) }}
```

but I got this error

```
A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in
parentheses (unexpected token "operator" of value "%" in AppBundle:Dashboard/Travel:form.html.twig at line 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delimiters like `{% ... %}` is used to execute statements such as for-loops.

Delimiters like `{{ ... }}` prints the result of an expression to the template.

You messed up with them. The right code would be:

```
{{ form_widget(form.showPrice, (travel is null ? {'attr': {'checked': 'checked'} }) ) }}
```

Comment: Thanks , but this works good when travel is null but if it is not null I got this error `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock() must be an array, string given, called in D:\wamp\www\agence\app\cache\dev\twig\ff\3e\245f88bde08490efe84c9aa31edb90139aa09d4ffd1773d1e01ec54eca40.php on line 181 and defined") in AppBundle:Dashboard/Travel:form.html.twig at line 100.`

Comment: try to wrap second argument in parenthesis. I updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
{{ form_widget(form.showPrice, (travel is null ? {'attr': {'checked': 'checked'} } : {}) ) }}
```

you need to also pass the false option - in this case `{}`